# adjust a non normally distributed numerical variable for a categorical covariate

Tags: covariance, ancova

Length of hospital stay was measured in 3 groups of patients (group 1,2,3)
the length of stay is numerical continuous e.g. 4 days of 6 days

one of the other variables is a confounder measured as a categorical value 0 or 1 (type of intervention: A=0, B=1)

can i use ANCOVA given LOS is not normally distributed and my covariate is a categorical variable ? what would be best way to test difference in LOS in the three groups while adjusting for type of intervention

Regards,

Comment: i did that LOS was different according to intervention. Now i need to adjust my LOS mean for the effect of Type of Intervention and compare LOS between groups

Answer (score 2):

Variables describing how long it takes before a certain event happens are typically modeled using survival analysis instead of ANCOVA.

Non-normality is one issue that this method deals with. Another is that often not everybody got the event when the study finished, e.g. some of your respondents may still be in hospital when you stopped collecting the data, or some may have died in hospital. What would be the length of stay for those respondents? Survival analysis is designed to deal with both (and more) issues.